# How to combine cover page and chapter contents of epublib in single WebView?

Tags: java, html, android-studio, webview, epublib

So, I'm trying to load the cover page and the chapter contents(in its respective sequence) within a single WebView using Epublib. So far, what I've done ... I retrieved my epub file from the cloud and unzipped in using the epublib library using the following code:

```
try {
    EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
    Book book = epubReader.readEpub(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
    return book;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception: ", e.toString());
}
```

Upon unzipping, I have access to cover.xhtml and chapter-1.xhtml (along with some other files) which I write to a file inside temp directory:

```
private File writeFile(File tempFile, String fileData) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    bWriter.write(fileData);
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    return tempFile;
}
```

Now, what I've tried was import the cover.xhtml page inside the chapter-1.xhtml page assuming that it would load in a single WebView.

```
//get file to load on webview
File file = new File(contentFilePath);

// Check if content file exists or not
if (!file.exists()) { System.out.println("Does not exist");}
else { 
    System.out.println("Exists");
    
    String contentData = readFile(file);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(contentData);
    doc.head().prependElement("link").attr("rel", "import").attr("href","cover.xhtml");
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://"+tempDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/", contentData, "application/xhtml+xml", "UTF-8", null);

}
```

However, this doesn't seem to load the cover page although the contents page is showing. Any help is much appreciated.